# Inserting a line of code in a method only when unit-testing

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, reflection, preprocessor, lines-of-code

Hello i am unit testing a method which deals some `I/O` operations.I was wondering if there is some kind of way to pause that method for a specific time , **at a specific line** , without altering the original code.

**Original Method**

```
public async Task<int> SomeMethodAsync()
{
    var x=DoSomething1();
    int value=await DoSomething2Async(); 
    return value;
}
```

Look at the method above.Is there any way from a `TestCase` to add a delay or a pause at a specific location in the target method?
I would like my method to become something like this **Only when unit testing** !:

**Desired method when unit testing**

```
  public async Task<int> SomeMethodAsync()
    {
         var x=DoSomething1();   //line index=0
    #    await Task.Delay(delay) //delay set in the testcase
         int x=await DoSomething2Async();  //line index=1
         return x;  
    }
```

**Unit Test**

```
[TestCase]
public void TestSomeMethodWithDelay()
{
    var delay=1000;
    int desiredLineIndex=1;
    int result=await SomeMethodAsync();
}
```

As you can see i would like when testing a method to insert some code before a target line , in my case an `await Task.Delay(interval)` where `interval` is set in the `TestCase`.
I do not want to modify/pollute the source code with preprocessor directives for testing.The only other way i could think is to use something like `System.Reflection.Emit` and rewrite the target method when testing.

Is there some other elegant way?

**P.S** I just want , when running a particular set of tests to insert a delay between two `lines of code` without altering the original code.

**Update**
The `SomeMethodAsync` is from another `dll`.The code must not be changed  ! The `DoSomething2Async` is an external call.

Comment: Is `DoSomething1` or `DoSomething2Async` local or an external service call? easy to mock teh dependency to delay when awaited.

Comment: The source must not be changed .It is from the another `dll`. The methods must not be mocked.They are external calls.

Comment: What is the purpose of the delay?  Normally you try to make unit-tests fast and eliminate delays.  Whereever the production code waits for real time to pass, in unit-tests this is mocked such that the passing of real time is cut short, while still the desired order of events is maintained.